# Не работает php server на VsCode Linux

Tags: php

пытаюсь запустить php с помощью phpserver VsCode, однако постоянно выдает это
[image: сообщение при запуске vscode]

уже почти все пробовал, менял путь к самому php разными командами:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php",
"phpserver.phpPath": "/usr/bin/php",
"php.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php"
```

но ничего не работает. Я почти уже отчаялся xD

Comment: А сам php то у вас лежит по этому пути?

Comment: да, лежит. Проверил коммандой whereis php, и она указала именно этот путь